# Is it possible to hide inactive stores?

Tags: magento-enterprise, stores

Is it possible in Magento 1.12.0.0 Enterprise edition to hide inactive stores from the all stores view list?

Comment: Inactive stores automatically will not display in magento. Where it is displaying ?

Comment: In the All Stores View list in the administration area for places like, products - if it's not possible to hide these then that's fine.

Comment: you can't hide from there. I suggest don't hide them.

Comment: @BornCoder Please put your comment as an answer since it clarifies everything that OP needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inactive stores automatically will not display in magento.

you can't hide. I suggest don't hide them